# Is it possible to upgrade PHP to 5.3 on a Centos Kloxo installation?

Tags: php, centos, yum

I have a VPS running Centos with Kloxo on and I was wondering how I would upgrade the PHP to `5.3` - It's currently running `5.2.6`.

When I try and do a yum update I get the following errors:

```
    Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.4 for package: lxphp
---> Package postgresql-libs.i386 0:8.3.7-umask.7 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
lxphp-5.2.1-400.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libpq.so.4 is needed by package lxphp-5.2.1-400.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libpq.so.4 is needed by package lxphp-5.2.1-400.i386 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php53 from the yum repo

Centos5 has PHP 5.3.3 available,

Remove your current php

If you installed via yum you can also remove it that way

yum remove php

yum remove php-common

Then do "yum install php53"

Hopefully then the dependices will be resolved correctly. You might have to remove more but yum should tell you.